# Anylogic reset resourcePool agent parameter each day

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm modelling a call centre in AnyLogic. I have two agent types - calls, and call operators.

Each call operator has a variable that tracks the number of calls that they have answered, however I want this number to reset each day. The number of available resources changes according to a schedule, but units are preserved when capacity decreases.

Can anybody shed some light on how to go about this?

[callOperator description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuOzh.png)

[callsToday variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS11C.png)

[resourcePool object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGQBA.png)

I'm currently trying to use an event that triggers at the end of every day, but I can't work out how to correctly reference each call operator individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Drag in your `CallOperator` agent type next to the resource pool
2. turn it into a population of agents that is "initially empty"
3. Change your pool settings to "Add units to custom population": [image]
4. Select the population from step 2
5. Create a cyclic event that recurs daily
6. in the event, loop through the population and reset what you need, for example as below:

(dummy code):

```
for (CallOperator currOp : myPopulationFromStep2) {
    currOp.counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Marvellous! I needed to change the agent type to a population! Thank you :)

Comment: Marvellous indeed :)